# How do I creating Generic object from dynamically loaded Type?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I'm getting a `Type` using `Assembly` class as follows:

```
var asm = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(MyAssembly));
var t=asm.GetType("FULLY QUALIFIED CLASS NAME", true, true);
```

Then I create object from this type:

```
var obj = Activator.CreateObject(t, new []{ params });
```

Now I want to convert or cast this object to a `Generic` object (actually SubSonic Active Record Object).

```
var record = (ActiveRecord<PUT SOMEHOW TYPE t HERE>)obj;
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Can you not just make the fully qualified class name be the ActiveRecord<T>, instead of just the <T> part?

Comment: I don't think that's going to be possible. Casting is telling the compiler that you (the developer) *know* what the type is going to be, but you don't know that here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point of *static* typing is that you know the type at compile time.

What do you expect the type of the `record` variable to be? The compiler needs to know - it can't wait until execution time.

What do you want to do with `record` anyway? If the real goal is to create an `ActiveRecord<T>` object but you don't need to know the T for any other operations, then you'll need to use reflection with `Type.MakeGenericType` or `MethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod` depending on the `ActiveRecord` API (which I'm not familiar with)... but you're not going to be able to use the result in a statically typed way (that depends on T) in the lines of code which follow.

Does `ActiveRecord<T>` implement a nongeneric interface? If so, that's what you'd usually use after constructing the relevant instance.

If you can provide a link to `ActiveRecord<T>` documentation to show how to construct an instance, I'm happy to write the reflection code for you...

Answer (score 0):

your class must inherit ActiveRecord or by itself be ActiveRecord  .

you are trying to cast a type into another object receving the fomer as varible:

```
Cat c = new Cat();
List<Cat> l = (List<Cat>) c; // error.
```